# calculating subtotals for invoicing using js

Tags: javascript

I have three things I cant figure out, just learning JS, but I will start with the first one

Ok, I had some help from a couple of people yesterday, and one of them suggested I dont put totals in a text field, I had to figure out how to do that. So I incorporated a drop down menu with products, depending on the product you choose, the corresponding price for that item appears in the price per column.

Now the problem I am having is getting the item price X quantity = subtotal. I cant figure out now how to get the scripting figured out for that. Ill post the coding.

JS:

```
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var a = document.getElementById('A');
var b = document.getElementById('B');
item.onchange = function() {
    A.innerHTML = this.value;
    document.getElementById('result'+row).value = a * b;
};
```

HTML:

```
<form name="frm">
  <input name="add" type="button" value="Add Row"/>
    <table width="34%" border="0">
        <tr bgcolor="#B80000">
          <td width="5%"><div align="center"></div></td>
            <td width="43%">
                <div align="center">Item Description</div>
            </td>
            <td width="21%">
                <div align="center">Price Per</div>
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <div align="center">Quantity</div>
            </td>
            <td width="11%">
                <div align="center">SubTotal</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="center">1</div></td>
            <td height="43">
                <div align="center">
                   <select name="item" id="item" size="1">
  <option value="">Select Product</option>
  <option value="$200.00">iPhone 4</option>
  <option value="$300.00">iPhone 4S</option>
  <option value="$450.00">iPhone 5</option>
  <option value="$300.00">Galaxy S3</option>
  <option value="$450.00">Galaxy S4</option>
  <option value="$450.00">Galaxy Note ll</option>
  <option value="$600.00">Galaxy Note lll</option>
  <option value="$700.00">Galaxy S5</option>
  <option value="$500.00">HTC One</option>
  <option value="$650.00">HTC One M8</option>
</select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="center">
                <span id="A"></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div align="center">
                <input name="B" type="Text" id="B"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="center">
                <span id="result"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>

  <tr>
      <td><div align="center"></div></td>
        <td height="44">
            <div align="center"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="center"></div>
        </td>
<td>
            <div align="center">TOTAL:</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div align="center">
              <input name="Total" type="Text" id="Total" size="8" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td height="44">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="window.location.reload();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is also a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gomoguy/R6pCP/)

Comment: Just a side note: Be sure to recalculate the totals server side when someone is ordering else they could just change it and order stuff for free.

Comment: this is an internal invoicing system, for our staff to use, not for public, but useful info, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the fiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/yrQP9/1/, and this works.

I've removed all the `$` signs from the values in the item list.

```
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var a = document.getElementById('A');
var b = document.getElementById('B');
item.onchange = function() {
    A.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    b.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
b.onchange = function() {
    add();
}

function add() {
    // getting item.value and B.value (no need to use the display field for this.)
    var a = document.getElementById('item').value,
        b = document.getElementById('B').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "$" + (a * b);
}
```

But I do have some improvements:

1. Don't use ID's for referencing to the fields. Use classes and relative entries.
2. As the value for the items use a numerical value so that javascript can easily work with them.
3. Recalculate the totals server side, even if it's internal use only. Someday something will happen where you'll wish you'd checked it.

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfect. Do I ask a new question for my next problem? or just post it here?

Comment: If this answered your question accept it as the answer so that this is closed, the little v like checkmark left of the post. And to answer your other question: Any question should always be posted in a new question. Never ask a question on another question :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple changes I would suggest at the start:

1. Instead of value you should store the prices as numbers (200), and then format them as prices when displaying them. This would allow you to more easily do math with the numbers.
2. In the javascript you are multiplaying `a * b`. a * b are document elements, they aren't numbers. You're looking for `a.innerHTML * b.value`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R6pCP/3/)

Comment: ok, I took the $ sign out of the value, and changed the multiplication in the script to a.value * b.value. thanks for that tip